# What is the Time complexity of this sorting algo?

Tags: algorithms, sorting

So i was trying to write an efficient sorting algorithm and i came up with this method,

> Sorting an array in ascending order by flipping (exchanging) 2
>   adjacent integers not in the correct order until there is no such
>   pair.
>
> The leftmost swappable pair must be swapped first, i.e. the first pair
>   encountered while going from left to right, which is in the opposite
>   (descending order) should be swapped. Then the whole process should be
>   repeated.

and the code i wrote for this is given below

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    int a[n];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }


        int j=0;

        //Sorting Logic

        while(j!=n)
        {
            int p=0;
            if(a[j]>a[j+1] && j!=(n-1))
            {
              int t=a[j];
              a[j]=a[j+1];
              a[j+1]=t;
              p=1;
                  }
                  if(p==0)
            j++;
            else
            j=0;

        }



        //Printing the sorted array

        for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
        {   
          cout<<a[k]<<" ";
        }


}
```

In the best case it will give $O(n)$, but I am unable to figure out the worst case. What will be its worst case complexity? Is it $O(n logn)$ or $O(n^2)$?

Comment: Isn't this just [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)?

Comment: Nope..bubble checks the whole array..here we are checking for the leftmost swappable options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O(N^2).
In the worst case, each iteration before while loop terminates swap n-1 times. So n*(n-1) gives n^2 time complexity.

Comment: This calculation holds in the comparison model. In the time complexity model, there's an amortized linear-time scan before each swap in the case that the initial order is $n/2+1, n/2+2, n/2+3, ... , n, 1, 2, 3, ... n/2$. So the worst case running time is actually cubic.